# Excel VBA: Communicating via named pipe

Tags: excel, vba, pipe, named-pipes, kernel32

I am trying to setup communication via a `named pipe` in VBA unfortunately for some reason it never gets to the line `Debug.Print "Connected` in the server, nor does the client connect. Seems like a simple scenario but been trying to get this going for hours.

### Server

```
Public Sub Server()
      Const szPipeName = "\\.\pipe\bigtest"
      Dim hPipe As Long, readVal As Long, readBytes As Long, sendVal As Long, sentBytes As Long
      Dim sa As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES

      'Create the NULL security token for the pipe
      pSD = GlobalAlloc(GPTR, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH)
      res = InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION)
      res = SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD, -1, 0, 0)
      sa.nLength = LenB(sa)
      sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = pSD
      sa.bInheritHandle = True

      'Create the Named Pipe
      hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(szPipeName, PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX, PIPE_WAIT Or PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE Or PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE, 10, 1000, 1000, 10000, sa)

      'Create separate thread as client
      ID = CreateThread(nil, 0, AddressOf ClientThread, nil, 0, nil)

      Debug.Print "Created thread: " & ID
      Debug.Print "Connecting named pipe: " & hPipe

      res = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, ByVal 0)
      'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX NEVER GETS HERE XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
      Debug.Print "Connected"
      'Read/Write data over the pipe

      res = ReadFile(hPipe, readVal, LenB(readVal), readBytes, ByVal 0)
      Debug.Print "Read file: " & readVal

      'res = WriteFile(hPipe, sendVal , LenB(sendVal ), sendBytes, ByVal 0)
      res = FlushFileBuffers(hPipe)
      res = DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe)

      'Close the pipe handle
      CloseHandle hPipe
      GlobalFree (pSD)

   End Sub
```

### Client

```
Public Sub ClientThread()
      Const szPipeName As String = "\\.\pipe\bigtest"
      Dim sentBytes As Long, sendVal As Long, fSuccess As Boolean, readVal As Long, readBytes As Long

      sendVal = 500

      'Give server time to ConnectNamedPipe
      Sleep 2000
      Debug.Print "Connecting to pipe..."
      fSuccess= CallNamedPipe(szPipeName, sendVal, LenB(sendVal), readVal, LenB(readVal), readBytes, 5000)
      'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX NEVER GETS HERE XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      Debug.Print "Successful: " & fSuccess

      '...
   End Sub
```

Comment: I take it you have tried stepping through the code? Do you get an error message? Does this help https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/177696

Comment: Yes I have but the code simply hangs on the line above. Yes I am taking the code from the shared link - but the client is created within a separate thread (which I don't think should make any difference). I would appreciate even a VBS working namedpipe example.

Comment: Concerning ConnectNamedPipe, the documentation says _If hNamedPipe was not opened with FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, the function does not return until a client is connected or an error occurs. Successful synchronous operations result in the function returning a nonzero value if a client connects after the function is called._ So it seems thec lient doesn't connect. In the client part you could specify NMPWAIT_NOWAIT (0x00000001) to return immediately and not wait for the pipe.

Comment: Yes that is my guess that the Client is not connecting for some reason.  I will try to experiment with the flags. But not sure if this will change anything as this is a viable example and should work as is according to my understanding.

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with changing the flags. The pipe is definitely created but even within a single VBA process I am not able to read / write to the Pipe handle using ReadFile and WriteFile operations. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

(this is my first answer -- time to give back)

Let me show you an example of this working. In the following example, I'll give you the VBA macro module code for a a function Excel to send an message to a server, the server to read the message, the server to compose a response, and excel to receive the response. we'll do this using a message that is a string, but you can take this further and create a protocol you would like to use over this pipe.

Remember that Excel macros are single threaded and event driven -- and so the way it makes sense to use named pipes in excel is as a client -- to in response to an event, send a request to a server and receive a response from that server (much like a web GET or POST sends a request and gets a response then closes the connection)

In this example, we used the method CallNamedPipeA in kernel32
(note that this is written for 64 bit excel. If using 32 bit, you exclude the "PtrSafe") This method connects to a named pipe in Message Mode, sends a message, receives a message, and then closes the connection.

The c# server code is taken largely from a Microsoft example, but we must convert it to handle message mode and had it restart a new thread when each pipe is closed. Thus there are always 4 threads waiting for clients to connect.

Quick note on Strings. Remember Excel uses Unicode. We should use UTF8 or byte arrays over named pipes.

Call the sub testPipe in Excel to see this work.

Excel VBA (client)

```
Option Explicit

Declare PtrSafe Function CallNamedPipe Lib "kernel32" Alias _
    "CallNamedPipeA" ( _
    ByVal lpNamedPipeName As String, _
    lpInBuffer As Any, _
    ByVal nInBufferSize As Long, _
    lpOutBuffer As Any, _
    ByVal nOutBufferSize As Long, _
    lpBytesRead As Long, _
    ByVal nTimeOut As Long) As Long

Private Sub testPipe()
    Dim ms As String
    Dim mr As String
    Dim returncode As Long
    
    ms = "Message from client;Hello World"

    returncode = namedPipeMessageExchange("testpipe", ms, mr)
    
    If returncode <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Sent:     " & ms
        Debug.Print "received: " & mr
    End If
    
End Sub

Public Function namedPipeMessageExchange(pipe As String, messageToSend As String, messageReceived As String) As Long
    Dim res As Long, myStr As String, i As Long, cbRead As Long, sm As String
    Dim numBytes As Long, bArray() As Byte, temp As String

    Dim b() As Byte
    Dim blen As Long
    b = StrConv(messageToSend, vbFromUnicode)
    blen = UBound(b) - LBound(b) + 1
    If blen = 0 Then b = Array(1)


    numBytes = 1000000
    ReDim bArray(numBytes)  'Build the return buffer

    'Call CallNamedPipe to do the transaction all at once
    res = CallNamedPipe("\\.\pipe\" + pipe, b(0), blen, _
        bArray(0), numBytes, _
        cbRead, 3000)  'Wait up to 3 seconds for a response

    If res > 0 Then
        ReDim Preserve bArray(0 To cbRead - 1)
        messageReceived = StrConv(bArray, vbUnicode)
        'Debug.Print "received: " & messageReceived
    Else
        Debug.Print "Error number " & Err.LastDllError & _
            " attempting to call CallNamedPipe.", vbOKOnly
    End If
    
    namedPipeMessageExchange = res
End Function
```

c# (server)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

public class PipeServer
{
    private static int numThreads = 4;

    public static void Main()
    {
        int i;
        Thread[] servers = new Thread[numThreads];

        Console.WriteLine("\n*** Named pipe server stream with impersonation example ***\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for client connect...\n");
        for (i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
            servers[i] = new Thread(ServerThread);
            servers[i].Start();
        }
        Thread.Sleep(250);
        while (i > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numThreads; j++)
            {
                if (servers[j] != null)
                {
                    if (servers[j].Join(250))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Server thread[{0}] finished.", servers[j].ManagedThreadId);
                        servers[j] = null;
                        servers[j] = new Thread(ServerThread);
                        servers[j].Start();
                        //i--;    // decrement the thread watch count
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nServer threads exhausted, exiting.");
    }

    private static void ServerThread(object data)
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer =
            new NamedPipeServerStream("testpipe", PipeDirection.InOut, numThreads, PipeTransmissionMode.Message);

        int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        // Wait for a client to connect
        pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

        Console.WriteLine("Client connected on thread[{0}].", threadId);
        try
        {


            List<byte> intext = new List<byte>();
            do
            {
                byte[] x = new byte[1024*16];
                int read = 0;
                read = pipeServer.Read(x);
                Array.Resize(ref x, read);
                intext.AddRange(x);

            } while (!pipeServer.IsMessageComplete);
            
            string receivedText = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(intext.ToArray());

            string sentText = "I am the server!";
            pipeServer.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sentText));
            
            Console.WriteLine("Received Text: "+receivedText);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent Text:     " + sentText);

        }
        // Catch the IOException that is raised if the pipe is broken
        // or disconnected.
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        //pipeServer.WaitForPipeDrain();
        pipeServer.Close();
    }
}
```